# SpringMVC : Dropdownlist select multiple values Issue- 400 bad Request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

How to bind multiple select dropdown values to my model?

On clicking the submit button getting [400 bad Request-The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()]. It is the case of Many-to-Many, the problem is that the value should get persist in db table userrole (that have the mapping in User class) although the commandname is from User class.

Though in the browser network it can be seen the two values that are getting selected from UI.

userController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewUser(Model model,@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        String message = null;
        try{
            user.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            user.setPassword(EncryptionUtil.encryptMD5Hash(user.getPassword()));
            message = loginService.createUser(user);            
        }catch(Exception e){
            model.addAttribute("message", "Some thing went wrong !!!! Exception occoured");
        }
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "message";
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "userrole",joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "UserId", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Role> roles;

    }
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="roleId")
    private Long roleId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> user;
}
```

createUser.jsp

```
    <form:form action="registerUser.html" method="post" commandName="user" >
    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Assign Roles</td>
                            <td>
                               <form:select path="roles" multiple="true">
                                    <c:forEach var="r" items="${roleList}">
                                        <option value="${r.roleId}">${r.roleName}</option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </form:select> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>

<tr><td><input type="submit" value="create user"/></td></tr>            
</table>
</form:form>
```